# Permissions for CreateAPIView in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I looked at the code for CreateAPIView and nowhere in the creation process are permissions checked. So I decided to check them in the `perform_create` hook as follows:

```
class CourseList(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Create a course.
    A user can create a course if he/she is an instructor in
    the academy the course is to be created in.
    """
    serializer_class = CourseRef
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsInstructorInAcademy)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, serializer.validated_data.get('academy'))
        serializer.save()
```

where the permission looks like:

```
class IsInstructorInAcademy(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, academy):
        return request.user.instructor_set.filter(academy=academy).exists()
```

When I try to create a course, the initial permission check runs fine and the course is saved but immediately afterwards I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /api/courses/
Cannot query "Mathematics 11A": Must be "Academy" instance.
```

and this is raised at the permissions check, as a result of which the POST returns a 500 ISE.

(This is slightly hacky because I'm passing in the academy instance in the permissions check in the `perform_create` hook whereas the view really concerns courses. I considered using a permission `IsInstructorInAcademyOfObject` but for that, I would need to pass in an object which I cannot get unless the serializer is saved.)

What is the best way to check for permissions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue because you're tying business logic checks with permissions.

Instead of calling `check_object_permission`, perform your own check once it's deserialized and raise a `PermissionDenied` if it fails.

Comment: I'd like to understand the distinction between 'business logic checks' and 'permissions', because even here, the test is on a user. I'm checking if this is a certain kind of user, allow this/that.

Comment: sure, but your test implies you know the content of the request while the permission check is performed before the request's content is known.

Comment: I think the request's content is not the issue. The problem is with the academy instance (or do you mean that when you refer to 'request content?). But otherwise, when is the request content known? That aside, what is the best place to perform this check? Inside `perform_create`?

Comment: The request content *is* part of the issue because you check against the academy which comes from the request content... that said, perform_create is fine