# Accessing a hyperlinkedRelatedField object from a permission class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an api backend of something like reddit. I want to ensure that whoever is creating a post (model `Post`) within a particular subreddit is a member of that subreddit (subreddit model is `Sub`). Here is my latest effort, which works but seems pretty sloppy, and the serializer for some context.

Post ***permissions.py***

```
class IsMemberOfSubOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        elif request.data:
            # prevent creation unless user is member of the sub
            post_sub_pk = get_pk_from_link(request.data['sub'])
            user = request.user
            user_sub_pks = [sub.pk for sub in user.subs.all()]
            if not (post_sub_pk in user_sub_pks):
                return False

    return True
```

Post ***serializers.py***

```
from .models import Post
from redditors.models import User
from subs.models import Sub

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    poster = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        #queryset=User.objects.all(),
        read_only=True
    )

    sub = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='sub-detail',
        queryset=Sub.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'created', 'updated', 'title', 'body',
                    'upvotes', 'sub', 'poster')
```

The issue with this approach is that since 'sub' is a hyperlinkedRelatedField on the `Post` serializer what I get back from `request.data['sub']` is just the string hyperlink url. I then have a function, `get_pk_from_link` that uses regex to read  the pk off the end of the url. Then I can use that to grab the actual model I want and check things. It would be nice if there were a more direct way to access the `Sub` model that is involved in the request.

I have tried searching the fields of the arguments that are available and I can't find a way to get to the `Sub` object directly. Is there a way to access the `Sub` model object through the hyperlink url?

I have also solved this problem by just using a serializer field validator (not shown above), but I am interested to know how to do it this way too. Maybe this is just a bad idea and if so please let me know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, parsing the url is not the way to go. Since you want to perform the permission check before creating a `Post` object, I suspect you cannot use [object level permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) either, because DRF does not call `get_object` in a `CreateAPIView` (since the object does not exist in the database yet).

Considering this is a "business logic" check, a simpler approach would be to not have that permission class at all and perform the check in your [`perform_create`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) hook in your view (I had asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787962/permissions-for-createapiview-in-django-rest-framework) about this earlier):

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# assuming you have a view class like this one for creating Post objects
class PostList(generics.CreateApiView):
    # ... other view stuff

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        sub = serializer.get('sub') # serializer is already validated so the sub object exists
        if not self.request.user.subs.filter(pk=sub.pk).exists():
            raise PermissionDenied(detail='Sorry, you are not a member of this sub.')
        serializer.save()
```

This saves you hassle of having to perform that url parsing as the serializer should give you the `Sub` object directly.